# Angular Material Dynamic Form Array Validation Custom Message

Tags: angular, dynamic, angular-material, formarray

I am facing an issue with reactive form - angular material and also i am using a custom validation plugin ng2-mdf for validation. The issue that i am facing is creating a dynamic form with form array and i am getting only the required field message, where as i have created few more custom validations where the message isn;t shown

I am using Angular Material with angular 2 or more version.

Comment: Can you please add minimal code, related to your problem?

Comment: SAMPLE HTML
 <form name="testInformation" [formGroup]="testInformation" novalidate>
<div class="col-lg-6" *ngFor="let unit of testInformation['controls'].units['controls']; let i = index" [formGroupName]="i">
<mat-form-field appearance="standard">
<mat-label>Test</mat-label><input formControlName="test" matInput type="email" autocomplete="off">
 <mat-error><ng2-mdf-validation-message [control]="test" *ngIf="!test.pristine || !test.dirty"></ng2-mdf-validation-message></mat-error></mat-form-field>
</form>

Comment: You can use this for getting the error message, however i need the custom error message instead of required message   https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-wbfcer?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.ts

Comment: Still are you facing this or expecting answer?